# Class 'SoapClient' not found while running PHP script

Tags: php

I am integrating PHP with SalesForce using SOAP, and use XAMPP server. It gives me error `Class 'SoapClient' not found`. After I remove `;` before the `extension=php_soap.dll` and `extension=php_openssl.dll` and restart the server. then i try to execute PHP script it gives me error `apache HTTP server has stop working`.

Comment: make sure the Soap Client module is enable on your server first.

Comment: need more details on what version of xampp you're using, any errors in the logs? do you have php_soap.dll in your ext folder?

Comment: Xampp version 3.2.2. yes php_soap.dll file is in the ext folder. No any error

Comment: Are you sure there are no APACHE (not PHP) error logs? In the XAMPP control panel click on the "Logs" button then select "Apache (error.log)".

Comment: After removing ; when I run phpinfo(); it show me soap enable but other PHP script is not running

Comment: Yes In APACHE(error.log) it shows me error